# how to bind array of javascript to mvc4 razor listbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a array in java script

```
var aaa = ["school1,100"],["school2,101"],["school3,103"]
```

I want to bind this array to Multiselect Listbox of razor page.

Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery for binding Javascript array to the listbox. Below code will help you to bind JS Array to listbox.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

 var aaa = ["school1,100", "school2,101", "school3,103"]

 for (var i = 0; i < aaa.length; i++) {
     $('#listbox').append('<option>' + aaa[i] + '</option>');
 }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <select id="listbox" size="5"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="listbox" size="5"></select>
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById('listbox');
addOptions(select, aaa);

function addOptions(el, ar){
    for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = ar[i];
        el.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```